# How to Remove currency from syminfo.ticker

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

im trying to work out how to remove just the currency portion of the syminfo.ticker.
The reason i am doing it this way and not just using the syminfo.basecurrency is that for pairs like XRPDOWNUSDT and XRPUSDT.3S , i still need the down and 3s portions left in the text to push that into an alert message
i have the indicator set up to automatically get the currency and base currency from the chart pair and push them into the alert message but when they are seperated,  the down and 3s parts disappear.

Is there a way on TV to input the ticker and then tell the script to remove the USDT letters and then push the result to the alert message

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try str.replace (Pinescript V5)
Like this :

```
newString = str.replace(OldString, "USDT",  "", 0)
```